# Shoulda-helpers - Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm currently trying to set up my test suite and I can't seem to get should-helpers to work. I have never personally set this up before but I work on a project that has it implemented already. I think everything is setup how it needs to be but clearly I'm missing something. Looking for someone to point out what I'm missing. here is my code.

MODEL SPEC:

```
    require "rails_helper"

describe Subscriber do
  context "validations" do
    it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:first_name) }
    it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:last_name) }
    it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:email) }
    it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:password) }
  end
end
```

MODEL:

```
    class Subscriber < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  VALID_PHONE_REGEX = /\d{10}/
  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :last_name, presence: true
  validates :email,
            :presence => true,
            :uniqueness => true,
            :format => VALID_EMAIL_REGEX
  validates :phone_number,
            :presence => true,
            :uniqueness => true,
            :numericality => true,
            :format => VALID_PHONE_REGEX

  def date_joined
    created_at.strftime("%-m/%-d/%-y")
  end

  def expiration_date
    (created_at + 1.year).strftime("%-m/%-d/%-y")
  end

  def days_till_expired
    ((created_at + 1.year) - DateTime.now).to_i / 1.day
  end
end
```

GEMFILE:

```
 group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem "sqlite3"
  gem "rspec-rails"
  gem "capybara"
  gem "factory_girl_rails"
  gem "simplecov", require: false
  gem "shoulda-matchers", require: false
 end
```

ERROR:

```
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `validate_presence_of' for #  <RSpec::ExampleGroups::Subscriber::Validations:0x007fc257ea50d0>
    # ./spec/models/subscriber_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The error is the same for all four.

As far as I know that is all I need? let me know if you need to see more code?

Comment: haha that might be nice to know. one sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add following in your rails_helper.rb?

```
Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
  config.integrate do |with|
    # Choose a test framework:
    with.test_framework :rspec

    # Choose one or more libraries:
    with.library :rails
  end
end
```

Further, why you do you have require false?, you should remove require false from your gemfile.
GEMFILE:

```
 group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem "sqlite3"
  gem "rspec-rails"
  gem "capybara"
  gem "factory_girl_rails"
  gem "simplecov", require: false
  gem "shoulda-matchers", require: false
 end
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Two things, first - The require: false was on the project that I found this on so I included it for no particular reason outside of just trying to emulate the process before me. Second - Where should I put this in the file?

Comment: Also when I add this to the file I get this error `uninitialized constant Shoulda (NameError)`

Comment: `Shoulda` isn't loaded because you have require: false in your gemfile. so you should remove it